# Как спарсить инфо с сайта с recaptcha?

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

Есть 2 сайта с формами поиска информации, мой и чужой, на чужом стоит recaptcha в форме поиска (аякс запрос на скрипт). Требуется с чужого спарсить информацию, пользуясь формой поиска моего сайта.

**Мои действия.**

1 вариант. Загружаю на своем сайте рекапчу с публичным ключом для своего домена и отправляю разгаданный ключ g-recaptcha-response на чужой сайт. В ответ - ошибка 403. Вероятно несоответсвие моего публичного ключа и приватного того домена.

2 вариант. Пытаюсь загрузить у себя в песочнице рекапчу с публичным ключом чужого сайта - в ответ ошибка (на скриншоте).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос - как мне спарсить инфо с такого сайта?** Капчу не требуется взламывать, её будет разгадываать человек, это не проблема.

Напоминаю, данное осуществимо, сервис Rucaptcha предоставляет услуги разгадывания капч, в том числе и гугловскую рекапчу http://rucaptcha.com/api-rucaptcha#solving_recaptchav2_new

**Дополнено 04.10.2017:** Для пробы парсинга можете использовать форму с рекапчей на моем тестовом стенде http://dev.drupalworld.ru/recaptcha/ - имитация чужого сайта.

Comment: Да у них "негры" разгадывают эти капчи, а их сервис возвращает вам результат работы одного из негров, вот и все. Обратите внимание, что они "разгадывают" (человек распознает) только текстовую капчу. Вы же в примере, кажется, подключаете капчу, где кликнуть надо "я не робот" (или самую последнюю - невидимую). Такую капчу "неграми" не сломать.

Comment: @KAGGDesign нет, они разгадывают именно эту  рекапчу v2. Галочка или инвисибл - это одно и тоже. Пример https://rucaptcha.com/api-rucaptcha#solving_recaptchav2_new

Comment: думаю, там тоже "человеки-нажиматели" работают ("подождите 15-20 секунд"). у меня баальшие сомнения, что какая-то русская группа хакеров изобрела полностью автоматический программный код, способный взломать разработку крупнейшей IT-компании мира. В Гугл хакеры сидят покруче наших.

Comment: @KAGGDesign так я и хочу разгадать капчу, а не взломать ее программно, но как разгадать капчу с чужого домена? Загрузка капчи с токеном чужого домена дает ошибку, смотри скриншот выше.

Comment: вот некое исследование на тему https://www.blackhat.com/docs/asia-16/materials/asia-16-Sivakorn-Im-Not-a-Human-Breaking-the-Google-reCAPTCHA-wp.pdf

Comment: "Укажите полный URL страницы, на которой вы хотите решить ReCaptcha" - возможно они просто открывают вашу страницу, подменяют ключи что бы увидеть вашу капчу, и решают ее.

Comment: а с какой целью это делается?

Comment: Привет. Могли бы Вы прислать адреса сайтов?

Comment: @Anatol недалеким компьютерным пользователям комфортнее искать на 1 сайте, а не 30-ти. Делаю так сказать структуризацию информации.

Comment: Пиши проксю через curl с пробросом куков.

Answer (score 4):

Это можно сделать простым скриптом при достаточном везении. Если при создании ключей автор сайта не указал домен, на котором капча должна ра­ботать, то скрипт рекаптчи будет работать на любом домене. Конкретно это поле нужно было оставить пустым:

[image]

Если это было так, то вы сможете попросить разгадать ту же самую капчу у вас на сервере с тем же самым `sitekey`:

```
<form method="POST">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="/* ключ с того сервера */"></div>
<input type="submit" name="OK" value="Разгадать">
</form>
```

Google не сможет проверить с того сайт разгадывается капча, или с другого. У упомянутой вами РуКапча используется [самодельный браузер, в котором разрешена подмена](https://vk.com/id205114406?w=wall205114406_285) `window.location.href` без перезагрузки страницы. Очевидно, это не вариант для обычных гостей сайта.

Динамически этот ключ можно получить, но лучше будет кешировать его где-то чтобы не дёргать тот сайт каждый раз при открытии страницы.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://dev.drupalworld.ru/recaptcha/');
preg_match('#data-sitekey="([-_A-Za-z0-9]+)"#', $contents, $match);
$sitekey = $match[1];
```

Это было первое условие. Оно может быть выполнено если разработчик был ленив, и не стал получать ещё один ключ для локальной разработки, или не стал добавлять имя локального се­рвера к разрешенным в существующем ключе. Или не пользовался [специальным ключом для разработчика](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq). При создании ключа у вас в примере вы указали домен, значит такой трюк на вашем примере уже не получится провернуть.

Второе условие: необходимо чтобы на целевом сайте использовалась самодельная функция для отправки результатов на сервер Google, которая *не указывает* IP разгадавшего капчу в па­раметре `remoteip`. Этот параметр [пока ещё не является обязательным](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request). Если такого параметра нет, то Google не сможет проверить что человек, разгадавший капчу, и человек, зашедший на сайт, тот же самый.

Таким образом, если вам повезло по двум пунктам, то вы сможете разгадывать ту же самую капчу у вас на сайте. Если хотя бы по одному из пунктов вам не повезло, то пиши пропало. Простым скриптом такую капчу не обойти.

Comment: Вы же видели скриншот, соответственно первое условие не выполняется. Ключ не для разработчика.

Comment: да и как говорилось выше rucaptcha.com это как-то делает))

Comment: В ответе есть про то, как рукапча это делает. Даже с видео от разработчика

Comment: почитал, действительно подменить window.location.href на другой домен не представляется возможным в связи с требованиями безопасности.